# How can Sub-Atomic Particles be Visualized?

Tags: particle-physics, subatomic

Can you see or accurately visualise sub atomic particles or are they known only by maths and/or inference?

Comment: What is your definition of visualize? If we draw something using mathematical equations, isn't it a visual representation? Do you want to see it under light? Mind it, whatever techniques we use to visualize subatomic particles do actually use mathematical equations to draw something on computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see a nucleus and the nucleus of a hydrogen atom is a proton which is the same.  You can't see below that at least with a source of neutrons that [ISIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISIS_neutron_source) produce, but you can see down to the level of the proton.

Comment: The limit at ISIS is basically set by the beam energies and the strong nature of the neutron--nucleon interaction, higher energy facilities can problem finer distance scales.

Answer (score 2):

We can image the sub-structure of nucleons by a number of different techniques involving high energy scattering. The [results](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8617/520) are generally presented in terms of "[parton distribution functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parton_%28particle_physics%29#Parton_distribution_functions)" or "[structure functions](http://www.gwu.edu/~ndl/research6i.htm)".

One such experiment that I had some small relationship with (though not enough to be an author) was [NuSea (E866) at Fermilab](http://p25ext.lanl.gov/e866/e866.html) in the mid 1990s, which used muon Drell-Yan as the a probe to image the QCD sea in particular.